# How to create text files using table content for name and text inside in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, file, text, createfile

I have following table:

```
1    One    TEXT_ONE
2    Two    TEXT_TWO
3    Three  TEXT_Three ...
```

I want run SQL Query that will creates txt files in specific folder:

```
C:\Files\One.txt (Text inside - TEXT_ONE)
C:\Files\Two.txt (Text inside - TEXT_TWO)
C:\Files\Three.txt (Text inside - TEXT_Three)...
```

I'm not so good in SQL, so any help appreciates=)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own way. It's probably not absolute answer for my question, but the idea completed.

So, I've created `bcp` Command that needs to be executed from `Command Line`

```
'bcp "SELECT ColumnName FROM DBName.schema.TableName WHERE IDCol = ' + CAST(IDCol as varchar(2)) + '" QUERYOUT .\' + ColumnForFileName + '.txt -FullServerName -T -c'
```

You can run select statement in SQL. Here is my example:

```
  SELECT sp.[SessionPageID]
      ,sp.[SummaryBody]
      ,sp.[MainTableBody]
      ,sf.[FileName]
      ,'bcp "SELECT SummaryBody FROM WLS_3E_TIMELOAD_APP.dbo.SessionPage WHERE SessionPageID = ' + CAST(sp.[SessionPageID] as varchar(2)) + '" QUERYOUT .\SB_' + sf.[FileName] + '_Session.txt -SCHAKHAU-T430\CHAKHAU -T -c'
      ,'bcp "SELECT MainTableBody FROM WLS_3E_TIMELOAD_APP.dbo.SessionPage" QUERYOUT .\MB_' + sf.[FileName] + '_Session.txt -MYLapTOP\LOCAL -T -c'
  FROM [SessionPage] sp
  JOIN SourceFile sf ON sf.SourceFileID = sp.SourceFileID
```

If you run this kind of query in result you will get all your bcp commands, so you then can execute them from Command Line